# ¿Cómo imprimo el símbolo de backtick?

Tags: soporte

Para [una pregunta en particular](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/272686/existe-un-equivalente-a-0-1-variable-en-javascript/272689) me gustaría poder poner en la misma línea, el símbolo de backtick como código.

Es decir el símbolo

```
`
```

Publico la pregunta acá porque no sé si se trata de Markdown estándard o si es algo particular del sitio.

Comment: Una alternativa es hacer esto: `<code>&#96;<code>`